# make a button from Javascript snippet

Tags: javascript, animation

i got a piece of code that uses JavaScript and J Query to make an animated name.i was successful in getting the animation to work in the browser.Now i want to know if i can make the result of that java script code i.e the animated name to work as a button?

Code:

```
var red = [359, 100, 29.8]; 
var orange = [40, 100, 60]; 
var pink = [75, 100, 40]; 
var violet = [196, 77, 55]; 
var purple = [280, 50, 60]; 
var yellow = [199, 100, 22.9]; 
var myName = "ANIMATION"; 
var letterColors = [pink,red,violet,purple,yellow,green]; 
var bubbleShape = "square"; 
drawName(myName, letterColors); bounceName();
```

Comment: _"i got a piece of code..."_ Post it in your question please.

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: THANKS FOR THE VERY QUICK RESPONS,HERE IS THE CODE:

Comment: var red = [359, 100, 29.8];
    
    var orange = [40, 100, 60];
    
    var pink = [75, 100, 40];
    
    var violet = [196, 77, 55];
    
    var purple = [280, 50, 60];
    
    var yellow = [199, 100, 22.9];
    
    
    var myName = "ANIMATION";
     
    
    
    var letterColors = [pink,red,violet,purple,yellow,green];
    
    var bubbleShape = "square";
    
    
    
    drawName(myName, letterColors);

    
       
    bounceName();

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is lacking in any details, I did a google search for what you did provide, and found this:  http://www.codecademy.com/YiannisM/codebits/PGW89r

So your "animated name" is contained in a `<canvas>` like this:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Then you can attach an event handler to that `canvas` like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('canvas#myCanvas').click(function() {
    window.location = "http://google.com";
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply Joe. and yes that code was from code academy.will try it.Thanks :)

Comment: i tried it and it worked Joe.i have just started web designing and i was trying to make this work since the evening. thanks a lot :)

Comment: now instead of having an alert windows,can i use that button as a link to another page?

Comment: Oh, if that's what you want, then just wrap the canvas in a. `<a href="another_page"><canvas></canvas></a>`

Comment: i tried this:<a href="index.html"><canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas></a>

Comment: but it dint work,should i make any corrections? and should i remove the event handler that i used before?

Comment: it worked Joe. i wonder if am asking too many questions. how can i give that animation a button layout? and since you have seen the code in code academy,is there any way that i can get the animation positioned in the middle of  the display screen?

Comment: These are all separate questions for SO.